# Can you put another Linux type repository on a Redhat server?

Tags: debian, rhel, repository

I'm working on a Redhat Enterprise Linux server and need to set up a Debian mirror on it in order to push out updates. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I am using a RHEL 7 server to create an on prem Debian (more specifically Raspbian) mirror to update Pis across the network.@炸鱼薯条德里克

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Every repository has an OS it runs on, yet public repositories almost always support multiple distributions of Linux, as illustrated by [mirrors.cat.pdx.edu](https://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/).